# how to do recursion in python outside and inside loop

Tags: python, recursion

Below is the python code to get the longest concat str with count
I am not able to call the function again when in loop and out side loop I am not able to access `suffixString`

if i call outside the loop it's

```
  t = {"asds":"asds","asas":"asas"}

  def checkIfitsLongest(str1):
        for i in range(1, len(str1)-1):
            suffixString = str1[i+1:-1]
                if t.has_key(suffixString):
                    break
        checkIfitsLongest(suffixString)
```

Comment: This is not too clear, please try explain better what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, we cannot understand... Input given, ouput wanted. Clear purpose

Comment: after break i want to call checkIfitsLongest(suffixString) its not working

Comment: "It's not working" is not a good description. Are you getting an error?

Comment: When I try to run your code the error I get is that `t` is undefined. Also, the `global` keyword is almost never used in python. I've been programming python for 8+ years and I've used it maybe once or twice.

Comment: Don't indent `if t.has_key ...`. Thats a formal error and maybe also the reason why "It's not working"

Comment: @machineyearning `unexpected indent`? If you want to be precise I'll call it "formal error"... Is that alrigth?

Comment: @LPK no you're correct, I misread. But I strongly suspect the indentation mistake is just from copy-pasting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Putting some well-positioned `print` debugging statements we can see that your problem is not with scoping of the `checkIfitsLongest` function or `suffixString` variable.

```
t = {"asds":"asds","asas":"asas"}

def checkIfitsLongest(str1):
    print "checking", str1
    for i in range(1, len(str1)-1):
        suffixString = str1[i+1:-1]
        print "suffix", suffixString
        if t.has_key(suffixString):
            break
    checkIfitsLongest(suffixString)
```

Now run in the interpreter:

```
>>> checkIfitsLongest("asdf")
checking asdf
suffix d
suffix 
checking 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    checkIfitsLongest("asdf")
  File "C:/Users/me/Desktop/cccc.py", line 10, in checkIfitsLongest
    checkIfitsLongest(suffixString)
  File "C:/Users/me/Desktop/cccc.py", line 10, in checkIfitsLongest
    checkIfitsLongest(suffixString)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'suffixString' referenced before assignment
>>>
```

So we can see that `suffixString` is being passed down correctly. However it is never initialized when you pass an empty string into the function (never entering the `for` loop).

You need to consider how to check your recursive base case. Usually you do this at the beginning of your function.